# Two tangents $BC$ and $BD$ are drawn. Prove that $OB=2BC$

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, circles

[image: Here is the Figure]

Two tangent segments $BC$ & $BD$ are drawn to a circle with centre $O$ such that $\angle{CBD}=120^{\circ}$. Prove that $OB=2BC$.

What I've tried,

$BC=BD$[two tangents drawn from a single point to the same circle are equal]

$\therefore$ We can prove that $\triangle$ OBC$\cong$$\triangle$OBD

But, this gets me nowhere.

Comment: $OBC$ is a right triangle and one of its angles is $60^{\circ}$.

Comment: $CB = OB\cos 60^\circ$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already found $\Delta OBC \sim \Delta OBD$. Since $\angle CBD = 120^\circ$, you know $\angle CBO = \angle OBD = 60^\circ$. Furthermore, $\angle BCO = \angle BDO = 90^\circ$ since $BC$ and $BD$ are tangent lines. Thus $\Delta OBC$ is a $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle, so $OB = 2 \cdot BC$.

Comment: Why? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Abhishekstudent which part?

Comment: If it's the 30-60-90 part, you can also show that using trigonometric functions, i.e. since $\angle BOC = 30^\circ$ and $OBC$ is a right triangle, you have $BC = OB \cdot \sin(30^\circ) = OB/2$. Alternatively consider the circumcircle of $OBC$, its midpoint (call it $M$) is the midpoint of $OB$. Then $BM = CM$, and since $\angle CBO = 60^\circ$ $\Delta CMB$ is equilateral. Thus $CB = BM = \frac{1}{2} OB$.

Comment: I have got it!!